# Can an XSD complexType refer to itself?

Tags: xsd

```
<xs:complexType name="ConditionsType">
    <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="Conditions" 
                    type="ConditionsType" 
                    minOccurs="0" 
                    maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
    </xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
```

Would the above xsd portion work properly? (This is a stub example, of course - the actual type would contain more actual data elements).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, absolutely. You can define types recursively.

However, keep in mind that the `name` attribute is an NCName, while the `type` attribute is a QName, meaning that you may need an additional prefix in the latter if the schema has a target namespace.